# Consul usage with multiple IP addresses

Tags: consul

Does Consul work with the scenario where the IP address in “join” is reachable only for that node, the same address won’t be reachable from other nodes. And this IP maybe different than what is advertised.

Say Node A advertises IP A.1 and has join [B.1], but node C has join [B.2]
B.1 and B.2 point to B, but A cannot reach B with B.2 (only with B.1), so there should be no exchange of peer IPs for this setup to work.

Comment: You cannot, each agent need to be routable each other, As consul use serf. To manipulate advertise address you can use go-sockaddess so all of the agent routable each other

Comment: So consul/serf uses the IP address directly as identifier and it needs to be unique and accessible by all? Won't go-sock then won't work since it just does resolving on start

Comment: go-sock just library to get the IP Address that the consul currently reside in,
routing isn't responsibility of consul. you need to ensure that each host is routable each other. the configure the consul binding / advertise with go-sock templating